Coercive functions
Can we show that the function $f(x,y)=xy$ is coercive if the domain is restricted to x>0 and y>0?
I was learning about coercive functions. The definition is that $f$ is coercive over a set $A$ if for all sequences $\{x_k\}$ with $x_k\in A$, and $||x_k||\to\infty$, it holds that $\lim_{k\to\infty}f(x_k)=\infty$. A good example if $f(x)=x^2$. However, I am thinking on generalizations to multivariate functions and test my intuition. MY intuition would say that $f(x_1,...,x_n)=x_1x_2\cdots x_n$ would be coercive as it seems a generalization of $x^2$, and as we get higher normed vectors, the output of $f$ should explode.
For the 2 dimensional case I asked, I know that if the domain is $x\geq 0, y\geq 0$ then it is not the case, since we can pick $x=0$ and $y\to\infty$, and $f(x,y)$ will be identically 0. But if we restrict to positive values, can we show $f$ is coercive?

What about the sequence $(1/n^2, n)$?
